# Are these two identical, or is one better/safer than the other?

Tags: javascript, null, ternary-operator, logical-operators

I'm afraid that refinement on a `match` of a user-input string will result in an error, since `match`ing with a regex that has the `g` flag set and doesn't match the string will return `null`, which is unrefinable.

So I'm left with the two following options, and as far as I can tell, they're identical. But I just want to make sure I'm understanding it properly.

```
    var tldMatcher = /[^.]+\.?$/g
      , tld = str.match(tldMatcher) ? str.match(tldMatcher)[0] : null;
```

...and...

```
    var tldMatcher = /[^.]+\.?$/g
      , tld = str.match(tldMatcher) && str.match(tldMatcher)[0];
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: *Better* is subjective. Personally, I don't like either one, something like `var tld = null, matches = str.match(tldMatcher); if(matches) tld = matches[0]` would be better.

Comment: Don't call `match` twice. Call it once, store the result, and if it's not null, then extract the element in which you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I always use `|| []` when I use `.match` with `g`. That is:

```
var matches = str.match(/regex/g) || [];
```

This ensures `matches` will always be an array of strings (but possibly empty). In your case it could be done like this:

```
var tldMatcher = /[^.]+\.?$/g
  , tld = (str.match(tldMatcher) || [])[0];
```